# Transition to GameScene from GameOverScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to transition back to my GameScene from my GameOverScene. I have the following touchesBegan function but when I press the 'Replay Game' button it does not transition.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "replay"{
            print("Touching Replay")
            let reveal : SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
            let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the following used to create my replay node:

```
let replayMessage = "Replay Game"
var replayButton = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
replayButton.text = replayMessage
replayButton.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
replayButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, 50)
replayButton.name = "replay"
self.addChild(replayButton)
```

I get the following output:

> Touching Replay 2016-02-03 01:11:08.102 Test [1010:196002] CUICatalog:
>   Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom

Comment: It is probably because you are not touching the "replay" node. If I try your code on empty project, it works. About that warning...You should not be worried...Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34320470/3402095).

Comment: could be there's another view or sprite above it. if so, you can disable user interaction for that node or view.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi , try this :**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

        if let name = touchedNode.name {
            if name == "replay"{
            let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), duration:1.0)
            let GameOver = MainScene(size: scene!.size)
            GameOver.scaleMode = scaleMode
            view!.presentScene(GameOver, transition: transition)
            print("Game Over!")
            }
        }
    }
```